# Upgrade .net framework 4.5.2 on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database server on which SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed with .net framework 2.0,3.0 and 3.5.
Can i install .net framework 4.5.2 on this machine without any issue as its a production server.

Comment: More suitable for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Yes, you can install framework 4.5.2 without affecting SQL Sever 2008.